# pg_terminate_backend - how to enable its execution by a non-superuser?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm writing a function that kills all current operations running on the server, however, `pg_terminate_backend` only allows superusers to execute it. I've searched around but have failed to find a concrete solution or lead regarding this.

Is it actually possible granting a certain user permission to execute it without making that user a superuser?

Furthermore, I've managed to find some information about people using security definers. I've never used those and didn't really find a use-case of it with pg_terminate.

Anyone ever had any experience with this or knows whether this is possible?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your tags, fyi.

Comment: `select version()`?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.5494

Comment: _All users_ can call pg_terminate_backend, but only superusers can  terminate sessions other than their own.

Answer (score 0):

In recent PostgreSQL versions you could grant the user the `pg_signal_backend` role.

In an antediluvial version like 8.0, you'd have to write a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by a superuser, `REVOKE EXECUTE` on the function from `PUBLIC` and grant it to the user that needs to terminate backends.

Comment: It's Redshift not Postgres

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks.